# Scoreboard based on recent actions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, reputation-leagues

Currently, all of the monthly and weekly scoreboards seem to measure reputation gained based on all posts (I'm a new member, but this has been my experience so far, and I couldn't find any meta posts that disagree).

Is there a way to view a monthly/weekly scoreboard that measures reputation gained only on questions and answers *posted* in that particular month/week? My understanding is that old users with 100s of answers find it much easier to get 200 rep-points a day.

Comment: There is "Top Answerers" and "Top Askers" in the Top Users page of each tag, e.g. [javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/topusers).

Comment: True, but no aggregation of reputation across an entire site. @ShadowWizard